# Why is Python not fully object-oriented?

Tags: python, oop

I want to know why Python is not fully object-oriented. For example, it does not support private, public, protected access level modifiers.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this? By these expressions, Python is suitable for what applications (Desktop, Scientific, Web or other)?

Comment: Python is suitable for nearly everything, that doesn't rely on hard number crunching, but even then you can write these Parts in C. Encapsulation isn't that useful in a dynamically typed language. It only aides the compiler, even in Java you can(and sometimes need to) circumvent it via reflection. Encapsulation, IMHO, doesn't add any security, it just gives you the feeling that there is more security in place.

Comment: @extraneon : No , just for know .
@Wetzel : I agree with you on ' Encapsulation isn't that useful in a dynamically typed language '.

Comment: That is one **good** question. I use Python as often as I can, I *love* it, and yet not a day goes by that I don’t ask myself the same question. I *like* imposing some rules in an API …

Comment: Python is "full object oriented". "Object oriented" was a term coined, rather than defined by some language, such as Java. It is a computer theory. Python simply does it differently, but for good reasons. "Features" such as the ability to make attributes private have nothing to do with the utility of a language and everything to do with the subtle enforcement of good practices when using the language.

Comment: @orokusaki I know it's been 5 years, but... "the ability to make attributes private" is what computer theory calls Encapsulation and is one of the 3 pillars of OO. Now: is it still true that Python does not have "private", or has this changed?

Comment: @ТаняТ. I'm sorry to have to inform you that your professor might have let you down. Please just take a peek at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29 and note the key phrase, "one of two related but distinct points", just before the two bullet points nearest the top of that page.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Python doesn't support strong *encapsulation*, which is only one of many features associated with the term "object-oriented".

The answer is simply philosophy. Guido doesn't like hiding things, and many in the Python community agree with him.

Comment: +1, the right answer. Though I'd say: Python doesn't *enforce (information hiding/encapsulation)*. obj._field is "private" in that idiomatic python code won't access it unless necessary (dir() function, reflection, serialization, having to hack around limitation of legacy code which can't be changed).
And Python is more OO than e.g. Java or C++ or C#, as there are no primitives.

Comment: @delnan: You're right; Python doesn't enforce hiding/encapsulation. It also doesn't *support* hiding/encapsulation any more than C does. In fact, with no reflection, C supports hiding better than Python! :-)

Comment: Just FYI: C#'s primitives are actually derived from System.ValueType, which is derived from System.Object. In fact, C# is the only truly OO language I know, in that everything is an object.

Comment: @Motig Ruby too is truly OO.

Comment: The Python tutorial says, “nothing in Python makes it
possible to enforce data hiding—it is all based upon convention

Comment: Another OOP violation is that python allows to define a method outside of class

Comment: @Xenoprimate Smalltalk?

Answer (score 49):

Guido once said that "we are all consenting adults here". Here's the longer explanation from long ago: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html

There's an agreement that underscores mean private elements and you should not use them. Unless you know what you're doing and you really want to.

The link also mentions another way to put it in case of Perl:

> "a Perl module would prefer that you
>   stayed out of its living room
>   because you weren't invited, not
>   because it has a shotgun."

Comment: Love the quotes. I believe that having private instance variables is more than just for keeping programmers from *coming into your living room*. In a number of common cases (esp. in setter methods), you want your object to alter or format some data before it is stored internally by the object, for whatever reason. In this case, you can't expect another programmer to know how that variable should be stored or accessed. All of this logic can be incapsulated within getter and setter methods. And leaving ivars exposed is messy/confusing/misleading. That's pretty much my only argument for privacy.

Answer (score 14):

Access modifiers (public, private, protected, etc) are not required for [class-based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming). They are just a feature, like [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Answer (score 4):

I think Python is designed to be a hybrid.  You can write in object oriented or functional styles.

The hallmarks of object-orientation are abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism.  Which of these are missing from Python?

Object-orientation is a continuum.  We might say that Smalltalk is the purest of the pure, and all others occupy different places on the scale.

No one can say what the value of being 100% pure is.  It's possible to write very good object-oriented code in languages that aren't Smalltalk, Python included.

Python is useful in all those areas: scientific (NumPy), web (Django), and desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Python is more of a very practical, pragmatic language.

Concepts which offer value to the developer are put in, without too much consideration about theological concepts like "proper OO design" and stuff. It's a language for people who have real work to do.

I think Python is suitable for all kinds of environments, though Desktop is a bit difficult due to the lack of a single framework. For all applications it's handy to use a framework,
like NumPy for computational stuff, Twisted or Django for web stuff, and WxWidgets or other for Desktop stuff.

Comment: There's actually a hell lot software for GNOME that's written in Python, I've written a 11k lines one myself, the code is just incredible readable and maintainable, development is also really fast and there are bindings for nearly everything. But I have to admit that GTK is really cumbersome at times.

Comment: PyQT is the way to go! PySlide by nokia is even much better.QT is also now fit for business due to LGPL Thanks to Nokia!

Comment: Including fields in objects interface is _all_ but pragmatic, it makes refactoring a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is full object oriented?  Alan Kay said "Actually I made up the term "object-oriented", and I can tell you I did not have C++ in mind.".  Admittedly, he probably did not have python in mind either, but it is worth noting that Smalltalk also protects classes by convention, no mandate.

Answer (score -5):

A language is said to Full Objective Oriented if it has no primitive data types. Each data type we need to construct.