# Python class which instances' atributes can't be edited

Tags: python, class, methods, python-3.x, instance

What would be the most convenient way to create a class which instances' attributes can't be **changed** from outside the class (you could still get the value), so it'd be possible to call `self.var = v` inside the class' methods, but not `ClassObject().var = v` outside of the class?

I've tried messing with `__setattr__()` but if I override it, the `name` attribute cannot be initiated in the `__init__()` method. Only way would be to override `__setattr__()` and use `object.__setattr__()`, which I am doing at the moment:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        object.__setattr__(self, "name", name)
    def my_method(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "name", self.name + "+")
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        raise Exception("Usage restricted")
```

Now this solution works, and it's enough, but I was wondering if there's even a better solution. The problem with this one is: I can still call `object.__setattr__(MyClass("foo"), "name", "foo_name")` from anywhere outside the class.

Is there any way to totally prevent setting the variable to anything from outside of the class?

**EDIT**: Stupid me not mentioning I'm not looking for `property` here, some of you already answered it, however it's not enough for me since it will leave `self._name` changeable.

Comment: Nope, there is not. Not in pure Python, in any case. Why do you need this?

Comment: Not possible, but it's worth asking why you would even *want* to do something like that?

Comment: Maybe I need a read-only attribute. One decent example would be `STEAM_ID`, incase you people have used steam.

Comment: No, you don't need a read-only attribute. There is never (and I really mean that) any reason to totally prevent setting an attribute. Using `@property` will signal that you aren't supposed to do that, and that is all the "protection" you will ever need.

Comment: If you've never needed one, it doesn't mean anyone else wouldn't ever need it. I do, and if you disagree, you don't know enough.

Comment: @Mahi: to convince us you need a readonly attribute, you have to explain to us who might change it?  It will be code running in your same process.  If you don't trust that code to do the right thing, then you are screwed.

Comment: I've got a program (a game) which lets other people create add-ons for it. That's why I need to protect the attribute in every possible way, so that it cannot be changed by the add-ons. I'm just trying to prevent cheaters from the game, but still allowing add-ons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in pure python.

You can use properties to mark your attributes as read-only though; using underscore-prefixed 'private' attributes instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._spam = value

    @property
    def spam(self):
        return self._spam
```

The above code only specifies a getter for the property; Python will not let you set a value for `Foo().spam` now:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self._spam = value
...     @property
...     def spam(self):
...         return self._spam
... 
>>> f = Foo('eggs')
>>> f.spam
'eggs'
>>> f.spam = 'ham'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Of course, you can still access the 'private' `_spam` attribute from outside:

```
>>> f._spam
'eggs'
>>> f._spam = 'ham'
>>> f.spam
'ham'
```

You could use the double underscore convention, where attribute names with `__` at the start (but not at the end!) are renamed on compilation. This is not meant for making a attribute inaccessible from the outside, it's intent is to protect an attribute from being overwritten by a subclass instead.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__spam = value

    @property
    def spam(self):
        return self.__spam
```

You can still access those attributes:

```
>>> f = Foo('eggs')
>>> f.spam
'eggs'
>>> f.__spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__spam'
>>> f._Foo__spam
'eggs'
>>> f._Foo__spam = 'ham'
>>> f.spam
'ham'
```

Comment: Not looking for `property`, but since you also answered that it cannot be done and someone else might be looking for `property`, I'll just accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict way of doing encapsulation on Python. The best you can do is prepend 2 underscores `__` to the intended to be private attributes. This will cause them to be mangled with the class name (_*ClassName*_AttribName), so if you try to use them on an inherited class, the base member won't be referenced. The names are not mangled if you use `getattrib()` or `setattrib()` though.

You can also override  `__dir()__` in order to hide them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, I could've accepted this one just as well, and gave you an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You can use properties to simulate such a behavior but like Martijn said, it'll be possible to access the variable directly. 
Doing this is a signal of you not understanding Python philosophy, check this out.

[Why Python is not full object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325343/why-python-is-not-full-object-oriented)

The properties way:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, value):
        raise Exception("Usage restricted")
    x = property(getx, setx)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: Actually what OP wants is not possible in python, at least not following the zen.

Comment: Yes, I know.  The way the answer is presented makes it seem like it is possible, which is why I down-voted.  If you make the 'not possible' point in your answer I'll remove my down-vote.